# Does Seaborn come with Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, seaborn

I am trying to play around with Seaborn on Spyder (installed as part of Anaconda).

```
import seaborn as sb
```

returns:

ImportError: No module named seaborn
This despite the Anaconda website listing seaborn as one of the default packages and the seaborn site saying that Anaconda is the easiest way to get the package.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `import seaborn`

Comment: I installed it separately `conda install seaborn`.

Comment: that was a typo in the post. I did actualy import seaborn

Comment: Yeah, it was a while ago but I think I also installed it separately. Just use `conda install seaborn`

Comment: Just tried conda install seaborn in both IPython and Spyder and got errors

Comment: You need to do it in a command line (terminal). Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8

Comment: Check [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/)

Comment: @ayhan worked, although I used cygwin instead of the windows terminal.

Answer (score 9):

Since [version 4.3.0 dated 2017-01-31](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/changelog), Anaconda comes with seaborn installed by default. Try upgrading your Anaconda installation.

Answer (score 5):

For those using GUI (navigator), select Environments > root. On the right is a list of packages - installed, not installed, etc.

Select "not installed", search for seaborn. If it appears, then click the row, and select Apply button at bottom of that page.

If it doesn't appear, then something else is wrong with your install.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Just do conda install seaborn. If its installed it will updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Seaborn is imported as 'sns' so if you use that, that will be much easier for you initially (because all the code examples use that), and for others later when you share your code.

Have fun with Seaborn, it is an amazing package.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your anaconda install has seaborne (or any other package) in the terminal using `conda search seaborn`. If its installed, a long list of package versions will be displayed.

This wont tell you if its current so it may also be beneficial to upgrade anaconda entirely using `conda update --all`.