# How do I install Seaborn from the Command Prompt in a Conda environment?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, seaborn

I have Python installed (through Anaconda) on my Windows 10 machine and it seems that Seaborn is not installed by default when installing Python.
Therefore, I need to do a manual install. 
I have gone through this thread here at stackoverflow:

[Does Seaborn come with Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963841/does-seaborn-come-with-anaconda)

However, I am still a bit confused as to whether I need to run the command `conda install seaborn` from the root (that is, C:_) or whether I need to run it from a specific directory in the Command Prompt Window.

So as not to mess things, I prefer to seek for a correct answer before proceeding with the installation. Also, do I need to run my Command Prompt Window as Command Prompt (Admin)? Right now, I simply run the Command Prompt as a user to launch Python.

Thanks for your efforts in making this clearer to me.

Comment: Since [version 4.3.0](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/changelog), Anaconda comes with seaborn installed by default. Perhaps you should upgrade your Anaconda.

Comment: If you installed your Anaconda for all users, you may need to run CMD as admin. Otherwise, you can just run `conda install seaborn`.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks, I did just that!